# Wrong information set to a cookie

Tags: javascript, php

I tried setting a string from PHP to a cookie and get the value of that cookie using JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
<php 
 $date=date('Y',time()); //lets say the year is 2017
 setcookie("Year", $date, time() + 3600, "/");
?>
```

Then I get the value of the cookie using JavaScript

```
alert(getCookie("Year")); // getCookie is a function defined in w3schools.com
```

The result I get is 1970 instead of 2017.

Comment: the function defined on w3school setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) so you need to pass the third params as number of days no as timestamp

Comment: Are you sure your clock is set correctly?  The value of `$date=date('Y',time());` is simply a string/int of 2017 (or 1970 if your clock isn't set).  Try echoing the $date before you setcookie to confirm it is indeed 2017.

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason, the `$date` variable is equal to zero when it is being passed into `setcookie`.

I recommend you do the following test code:

```
<?php
 $date=date('Y',time()); //lets say the year is 2017
 echo "Date is = {$date}<br>";
 setcookie("Year", $date, time() + 3600, "/");
?>
```

If `$date` is 0, then you should have an issue with your computers clock.